# How can you display host IP address in bash prompt?

Tags: bash

Like above, I'd like to display IPv4 address of eth0 (or part of it) in PS1 or bash. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: define: ip address -- of which interface ? ipv4 / ipv6 ? localhost too ?

Comment: Is that supposed to say "in PS1 on (or in) bash"? Just checking.

Answer (score 11):

I use the following in my `.bashrc`

```bash
THEIP=$(ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | tail -1 | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')
PS1="\[\033[01;31m\]\u@"$THEIP" \w $\[\033[00m\] ";
```

This will show you a prompt of:

```bash
root@1.2.3.4 /opt/amazon/jungle $
```

Remove the `\w` to get rid of the present working directory or make it `\W` to make it only the a partial working directory

```bash
root@1.2.3.4 jungle $
```

You can also use the following, assuming that there is only one IP address in your `/etc/hosts` file:

```bash
THEIP=$(hostname -i)
```

Comment: Interesting solutions. Not sure what OS the OP is using, but in OSX, `hostname` doesn't have the `-i` option. You could do something silly like `host $(hostname) | cut -f 4 -d " "` if there is a DNS available.

Comment: The ifconfig output format has changed slightly (I'm using bash in ubuntu 18.04), and the 'cut' command does not seem necessary if the awk command is adjusted slightly, so I am using: THEIP=$(ifconfig | grep 'inet '| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | tail -1 | awk '{ print $2}')

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: literally no attempt made to make this less-rubbish.

Below is the way to do that...

```
PS1=$(ifconfig $(route -n | grep ^0.0.0.0 | awk '{print $NF}') | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | awk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 4):

As stated by Sirex you can do a lot of tricky things with command substitution, I would prefer the following declaration using the `ip` utility:

`export PS1="IP: $(ip addr show dev eth0 | grep "inet " | cut -d" " -f6) #"` or something like that.

Another option is to use the tool `facter` which provides a lot of information about your system so a simple `facter ipaddress_eth0` gives you the IP-Adress. So the new example would be

`export PS1="IP: $(facter ipaddress_eth0) #`

`facter` allows you to use much more system informations for scripting if you want. Just execute `facter` to see what it got in it's whole configuration. If you want you can also declare your own facts in `/etc/facts.d`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case: I have some VMs run Ubuntu server, each of them have private it's IPv4 address, and it should be nice if I can see the IP address each time I login (like EC2 Instances), and here is what I did:

- Add the following lines in the bottom of `~/.bashrc` file:

```
IP=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')
PS1="\u@$IP:\w\$ "
```

- Then type the command: `source ~/.bashrc`, and the IP is displayed
- I also use rsync to sync the `.bashrc` between multiple machines (examples: `rsync -avzhe ssh /path/to/file user@server:/path/to/destination`), hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This is the minimalist way. Feel free to add whatever other characters you need in PS1.

```
IP=$(hostname -i)
PS1='$IP'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've taken @SomeGuyOnAComputer's answer and improved it slightly:

`IP=$( ifconfig | grep ^eth -A2 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1 }' )
PS1='\n\[\033[00;32m\]\u@$IP \[\033[00;33m\]\w\n\\$\[\033[00m\] '`

I had a docker container running on my machine so it was picking up the docker's ip address when I ran @SomeGuyOnAComputer's command. The new version looks for the line that starts with 'eth' and prints the 2 lines after the matching line (-A2) information. The rest is just like @SomeGuyOnAComputer's version.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this config in .bashrc and is pretty cool (similar to suggested above)

```
pyclean () {

        find . -type f -name "*.py[co]" -delete -print
        find . -type f -name ".DS_Store" -delete -print

        find . -type d -name "__pycache__" -delete -print

}
IP=$( ifconfig | grep ^eth -A2 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1 }' )
export PS1="\e[1;32m\D{%T} @$IP\e[1;34m\w/\e[m\n\$ "
```

Comment: 00:02:03 @10.112.202.108~/shahid/ansible/
$

Answer (score 0):

You may also like this-

```
IP=$( ifconfig | grep ^eth -A2 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1 }' )
PS1='\e[1;34m\D{%T} \[\033[00;39m\]\u\[\033[00;32m\]@$IP \[\033[00;33m\]\w/\n\\$\[\033[00m\] '
```

Answer (score 0):

## IP Address in Prompt With Automatic Updating

My solution was as follows (works on Fedora). Adapted from the the other answers here and info from this post http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2008/12/18/use-networkmanager-launch-scripts-based-network-location/.

Create the following script as root:
`/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99smartsynergy.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
# http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2008/12/18/use-networkmanager-launch-scripts-based-network-location/

IF=$1
STATUS=$2

if [ "$STATUS" = "up" ]; then
        ip=$(/usr/sbin/ip addr show dev $IF | grep "inet " | cut -d" " -f6)

        echo -n $ip > /tmp/ip_address.txt
        chmod a+w /tmp/ip_address.txt
fi
```

Then in your `.bashrc`:

```
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
WHITE='\e[97m'
GREEN='\e[0;32m'

touch /tmp/ip_address.txt
export PS1='\['$GREEN'\][\d \t \u@\h \W][\'$WHITE'\]$(cat /tmp/ip_address.txt)[\'$NC'\] \$ \[\e[m\]'
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

`````
if [ ! -f "/tmp/ip/last" ]
then
        firstread=1
else
        lastModificationSeconds=$(date -r /tmp/ip/last +%s)
        currentSeconds=$(date +%s)
        ((elapsedSeconds = currentSeconds - lastModificationSeconds))
fi

if [[ $firstread || $elapsedSeconds -gt 1800 ]]
then
        mkdir -p /tmp/ip >/dev/null 2>&1
        curl -s  ifconfig.me > /tmp/ip/last
        chmod a+rw /tmp/ip /tmp/ip/last >/dev/null 2>&1
fi

PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@`cat /tmp/ip/last`\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '````
`````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: not sure what is unclear, Mr. bot. please be more specific

Answer (score -2):

Export your IP variable:
export MYIP=$(ifconfig | grep inet | egrep -v "127|inet6" | awk '{print $2}')
Export your bash variable:
export PS1='[\u@"$MYIP" \W]\$ '

Comment: (1) Why would exporting help?  (2) You know that ``192.168.1.127`` is a valid IP address, right?